# Querying polymorphism in RDF database using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a question about polymorphism in RDF schema.

I created a class "MobilePhone":

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix my: <http://localhost/> .

my:MobilePhone rdf:type rdfs:Class .
my:MobilePhone rdfs:subClassOf schema:Product .
my:MobilePhone rdfs:label "MobilePhone" .
```

Then I executed two queries:

```
PREFIX : <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX my: <http://localhost/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?instance
WHERE {
    ?instance a my:MobilePhone . 
      }
```

and

```
PREFIX : <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX my: <http://localhost/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?instance
WHERE {
    ?instance a :Product . 
      }
```

I expected the second query to retrieve all Products. Even "MobilePhone" products. But that didn't happen. I had to use:

```
PREFIX : <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX my: <http://localhost/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?instance
WHERE {
    ?class rdfs:subClassOf* :Product .
    ?instance rdf:type ?class .
}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to update my schema so the first query for searching all Products would work?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to update your *data* (not your schema [or ontology]) to deliver the desired result, by "forward chaining" -- i.e., by explicitly including statements that each entity which is `a my:MobilePhone` is also `a :Product`.

It's also possible to use "backward chaining" to deliver the desired result; the specifics of this will vary with your triple/quad store and other software.  ([My employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/)'s solution, [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), uses a `DEFINE input:inference` pragma to [activate an inference rule set for each query](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/tutorials/sparql/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_5/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_5.html#%2866%29).)

Both of these may be considered as "inferencing" or "reasoning", though common usage generally applies these terms only to the dynamic action -- which happens with every query in "backward chaining", and once, pre-query, typically during data load, in "forward chaining".

Comment: A somewhat odd way to phrase things. "Forward chaining" and "backward chaining" are _both_ forms of inference.

Comment: In a sense, you're correct.  I don't usually think of "querying over static data" to be "using inference," even if inference was used to produce that static data.  In my experience, common usage agrees with my thinking.  Your mileage may differ...  Possibly also worth stating, neither option is an "update [of @Mayda's] schema".

Comment: Given the wide variance described cogently here, it seems the most dependable, cross-system compliant, choice is to use the `rdfs:subClassOf*` SPARQL query.

Comment: Ted, in your answer, you're confusing forward chaining with materialisation. Although it is fairly common to use forward chaining for materialisation, it is not necessarily the case. It is also possible to materialise what you infer by backward chaining. This is the equivalent of caching the inferences. In cases where the size of the inferred data is massively bigger than the explicit facts (e.g., several orders of magnitude bigger), materialisation is not practical.